# Access public partial class variable in another class

Tags: c#

I  have a class with following structure :-

```
namespace CL.Forms
{
    public partial class A
    {
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("a");
        sb.Append("b");
    }

    public class B
    {
        A objA=new A();
        string s= objA.sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

I want to access the varible in class `A` from class `B`. I tried the above method. But it doesn't work. Anyone knows the answer. Please help me.

Comment: doest it even compile?

Comment: @Selman22 Probably not, may be that's why he is here.

Comment: Hi, this won't work at all, you cannot call methods and declare variables in your class body. I am afraid that you won't get an answer of how to start here, you don't seem to understand basic concepts of OOP... First, you need to declare something in the class, i.e. methods, constructors, fields and properties. Then, you need to instantiate the class... When you know what these mean (google for it, you'll find plenty of information), you'll know the question you want to ask, and maybe even the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a constructor or method

```
namespace CL.Forms
{
    public partial class A
    {
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

       //Constructor to set default for string builder
        public A()
        {
            sb.Append("a");
            sb.Append("b");
        }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public B()
        {
            A objA=new A();
            string s= objA.sb.ToString();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code(s) inside of a method, like constructor:

```
public partial class A
{
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public A()
    {
       sb.Append("a");
       sb.Append("b");
    }
}

public class B
{
    A objA = new A();
    public B() 
    {
        string s = objA.sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace CL.Forms
{
    public partial class A
    {
        //decalring sb
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //giving sb default values incase you dont change it just call the variable but it has
        //but it has to happen in a method
        public A()
        {
            sb.Append("a");
            sb.Append("b");
        }
        // a seperate methode to return sb
        public StringBuilder getSb()
        {
            return sb;
        }
    }
    public static class B
    {
        //same stuff
        A objA = new A();
        public void methodNameHere()
        {
            string s = objA.sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

try this, you forgot to implement methodes in your classes.
that is crucial else it wont work. But maybe it is better if you just google some tutorials for OOP.